# Playing Heroes of the Storm with Steam Overlay

Tags: steam, heroes-of-the-storm

When you launch Heroes of the Storm directly, it would just take you to Battle.Net. The same is the case with Diablo 3. Adding the parameter -launch to D3 circumvents Battle.Net though and you can log in and use the Steam Overlay by adding D3 with this command line parameter as a Non Steam Game.

However, this does not seem to work with Heroes of the Storm. Is there any way to launch Heroes of the Storm from Steam with the Overlay enabled for streaming?

Comment: I believe you can choose to launch Battle.Net as a game, and then launch the games inside, and they will contain the Steam Overlay. Not a solution, but maybe you could use a workaround.

Comment: @Zerjack wont work unfortunately, since the battle.net process closes after launching the game (see options).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sort of how you must actually use the direct Diablo 3 executable to launch it as a non-Steam game, so too must you use the direct HotS executable to launch it as a non-Steam game.

The difference is, with HotS it's not as simple as the direct executable instead of the launcher sitting in the same directory. What you are looking to launch is:

```
PATH/TO/HEROES/Support/HeroesSwitcher.exe
```

You will need to ensure that the game is kept up to date via the Battle.net launcher, however, and you will need to log in as normal, but as you can see in [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmeNY.jpg), it works fine.

(This information was found on the [official HotS forums](http://us.battle.net/heroes/en/forum/topic/12674628104) and verified by personal testing.)

Comment: This is the workaround I used for Starcraft 2 as well with sc2.exe